# IIS bindings: www.domain.com is working but domain.com not

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, azure

I've just added a windows server 2012 R2 VM in Azure, with IIS installed.
Now i want to use multiple domains on that server.

So i went to the domain provider and edited the DNS records:

```
From                 Type          To
------------------------------------------------------------
domain.com           A             187.116.196.178
www.domain.com       CNAME         domain.com
ftp.domain.com       CNAME         domain.com
```

And i set bindings in IIS to a site:

```
Host Name            Port          Ip
------------------------------------------------------------
domain.com           80            10.1.0.4
www.domain.com       80            10.1.0.4
ftp.domain.com       21            10.1.0.4
```

The cloud service in Azure has a public IP of `187.116.196.178`. And the VM is connected to that cloud service. This is working. (If i add a website without host I can get it on 187.116.196.178:80 publicly).

Now a strange thing happens: `www.domain.com` but `domain.com` not. Also when i try to connect with the ftp server, i get the message: `530 Valid hostname is expected.`

How does this happened? And how can i set the DNS and IIS to work properly?

Comment: on the face of it - that should work. I haven't done much with Azure specifically but I have run some sites that have both the form of domain.com (A record) and sub.domain.com (as a C-Name) and with bindings require host names and not had any issues.
(not sure about FTP - I don't think I've ever required host name for those). Do you have an azure VM - or are you using one of the web app services? perhaps there's a setting you need to define on the Azure interface somewhere ?

Comment: Yeah i though so... I'm using a VM, not a webapp. I can configure endpoints: map private ports from the server to a public port. And i have a DNS-name and a IP adres. The strange thing is: `www.domain.com` is working... So it looks like it goes trough Azure.

Comment: So what exactly happens if you use `domain.com`, do you get anything back in the browser, a status code? I would first try to verify that the request actually reaches the correct server.